# How to use google maps api in angularjs to get list of cities between two markers (cities)

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to show list of via point major cities when user enters/selects starting and end locations. I'm using angularjs and google maps api. Please let me know if this is possible or not?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Do some basic research, try a few examples that you find and if you encounter errors you can then post more specific questions for the community to assist.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking is most definitely *possible*, but not *trivial*. In addition to the google maps API, you will likely need to use another tool provided by google: their [Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#RadarSearchRequests).

This API would allow you to input a location and receive information about nearby landmarks, establishments, etc. The places API could be called from an Angular 1 service and then filtered or further manipulated to retrieve only results that are considered "major" to your users.

Depending on how accurate/specific you need your data to be, you should also consider using the [American Census data API](http://www.census.gov/data/developers/data-sets/acs-1year.html). You can compare the results from your google places API results and use real, accurate government data to check the population of regions or cities.

So to answer your question: Yes, it is most definitely possible although it certainly doesn't require Angular.